# Construct dynamic HTML table with Add/Remove rows

Tags: list, custom, form

I have created a custom edit form using SharePoint Designer 2013. After the existing fields, I would like to create a table with the provision to the user to add/remove table rows dynamically. The information entered needs to be saved along with the item. Kindly advise on how I can achieve the functionality without using InfoPath.

Thanks,

Comment: Where does this info from the table need to be saved ? Are they going to be stored in fields on the original item or as seperate items ? Are you looking for a bulk edit form ?

Comment: The information needs to be stored in one of the fields in the original item upon save. No I am not looking for bulk edit form. The table I am creating is to capture Recipient details and the gifts that will be handed over to them. Thanks.

Comment: The table will be saved in a multi value field of some kind, maybe a lookup to another list ? As @Yandr suggests, you could use JavaScript for the rows functionality and save it to the field in it's expected format (depends on the field type). This way saving the item will also save the fields back to SP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is highily dependent on what you are trying to achieve.

You could try using jquery to allow users to add/remove rows and then save all the entries to a single text field, using a delimiter of your choice.

When displaying the information to the user, you will need to read the text field again and use the delimiter to separate the value into different rows.

In summary:

1. In the UI (javascript) you create and delete rows
2. You have a hidden input element for the text field that will actually hold the value
3. When the user clicks SAVE, javascript runs through the rows and 'collects' the values. It concatenates them to a string like VALUE1#;VALUE 2#;VALUE 3 and it save them to the hidden input field
4. The hidden input field is saved to the Sharepoint field.

Comment: Hi Yandr, thank you for the reply. I have created a create custom edit form using sharepoint designer. I am confused on 1. How to integrate the JS file with the custom form 2. How to set values back to sharepoint form field during save. Please advise.

Comment: Well the answers to these questions is not straight forward. 1- Why you want to integrate javascript with the form. 2- If you are using javascript then you might consider SharePoint Javascript client object model.

Comment: To integrate jquery you just need to add a reference to the js file in the custom form <script src="yourpath/jquery.min.js"></script> and of course you need to add jquery in one of your libraries.

I added some more information in my answer, in case this helps.